# Default Design view, dropping any tool box items goes completely off page?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

Ok, so i am doing a project with ASP.net, and using Visual Studio 2012. I created a new master page, in which i wish to make registration. I simply drop the "Create User Wizard" in the Login toolbox onto my page, and it goes completely off its hinges!!

[image: In Internet Explorer]

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="Register.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1.Register1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">
  <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server" Height="10px" Width="10px">
            <WizardSteps>
                <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep1" runat="server">
                </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
                <asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="CompleteWizardStep1" runat="server">
                </asp:CompleteWizardStep>
            </WizardSteps>
        </asp:CreateUserWizard>
    </asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

I cannot get anything inline like my previous pages.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why add logon control to master page? Master page is simply your top (and perhaps bottom) template that displays objects for EVERY page. Your master page in the screen cap even shows "navigation" options that again one needs/wants to appear for every page. Such a logon page should be a standard web form and NOT some master page. Attempting to drop in a logon control in the top part of this master page that been formatted to ONLY take up the top part of the web page makes no sense. Adding such a control as you have will make that control appear on every page that uses this master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not because wizard or something, it's about styles. You have a better browser (Chrome), just open your page in Chrome, right-click on desired element and choose "Inspect element".

Then take a magnifier:

[image]

Point this tool to desired element and check out styles on the right:

[image]

Try to enable/disable them right there, and you'll see result immediately.